# tomcat6 on centos 5.5 not stopping

Tags: centos, tomcat6

Configuring a server for a friend, first time I've dealt with Tomcat and I'm close to tearing what little hair I have left, out :)

For his project he needs to use a PHP Java Bridge, I've got the server to the point that Tomcat6 is installed and running, as is the bridge. He can access it via a localhost call like this:

```
<?php require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");?>
```

This all works fine.

```
[root@server home]# wget -q http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc
[root@server home]# ls | grep Java.inc
Java.inc
```

Service is running nicely:

```
[root@server home]# ps ax | grep tomcat
44747 ?        Sl     0:03 /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -classpath :/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat6/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
[root@server home]# /etc/init.d/tomcat6 status
tomcat6 (pid 44747) is running...
```

Now, if we ever need to restart - I'm getting this:

```
[root@server home]# /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
Stopping tomcat6:                                          [FAILED]
Starting tomcat6:                                          [  OK  ]
```

Somewhat perplexing, if I kill the pid and then start I end up with

```
[root@server tomcat6]# /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
: command not found6.conf: line 10: 
: command not found6.conf: line 13: 
: command not found6.conf: line 19: 
: command not found6.conf: line 22: 
: command not found6.conf: line 25: 
: command not found6.conf: line 28: 
: command not found6.conf: line 31: 
: command not found6.conf: line 34: 
: command not found6.conf: line 37: 
: command not found6.conf: line 40: 
: command not found6.conf: line 43: 
: command not found6.conf: line 46: 
Starting tomcat6: chown: `tomcat\r:tomcat\r': invalid user
chown: `tomcat\r:tomcat\r': invalid user does not exist, creating
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/share/tomcat6\r/work' to `/var/cache/tomcat6': No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/share/tomcat6\r/temp' to `/var/tmp/tomcat6': No such file or directory
chown: `tomcat\r:tomcat\r': invalid user
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Any ideas?

Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this sounds like someone has edited `/etc/init.d/tomcat6` script in some Windows text editor and now the script has DOS line feeds instead of Unix line feeds, which confuses the init system.

Use `file /etc/init.d/tomcat6` to check if this is true. If it is, use for example `dos2unix /etc/init.d/tomcat6` to convert the file to Unix line feeds.

Comment: Seems ok:[root@server home]# file /etc/init.d/tomcat6
/etc/init.d/tomcat6: Bourne-Again shell script text executable

Comment: Double-check with `cat -vT /etc/init.d/tomcat6` -- if you see ^M characters at the end of the lines, then it's in DOS format. I still suspect this due the \r stuff going on in your 'screenshot' :)

Comment: Nope, definitely ok. Ran it through dos2unix just to be safe - same issues.

Comment: If you manually inspect that file, are there those \r characters all around, then?

Comment: Oh! Now I got it. Most likely some of your Tomcat configuration files are in DOS format. Do check those next. :)

Comment: Ah. Think I've got it. I read through the actual tomcat6 script, and have narrowed down where the error log is. I'm getting Could not reserve enough space for object heap errors when it's trying to pass the stop command. This is a VM so will look at increasing limits.

Comment: But that does not explain all that \r flood you're seeing during start. Those are coming from somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, that is weird - all the conf files are checking out ok. I only access this machine from a FC12 install - I guess the other guy might have broken it but I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Time for some detective work! See from init script what variable is used in that `chown` part. Then see where that variable is defined. Clearly the user and group are defined somewhere where they are in their own lines and in DOS format...

Comment: One great place to mess this kind of things up is under `/path/to/your/tomcat/bin` -- the scripts under there are heavily used during Tomcat startup.

Comment: Found it. cd /usr/share - ls drwxr-xr-x   3 root root    4096 Nov 10 10:12 tomcat6
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root    4096 Nov 10 10:10 tomcat6?

Comment: Yeah. Try to examine files under `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin`, that might be the place with the rebel DOS files.

Comment: Yeah, there's a whole folder which has DOS'd files all over the place. Idiot developer :(

Comment: So there's your problem. `dos2unix` all of them and magically see your mysterious problem disappear! I hope.

Comment: [root@server tomcat6]# /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
Stopping tomcat6:                                          [  OK  ]
Starting tomcat6:                                          [  OK  ]

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I know your pain of installing/maintaining software provided by others ...